# About convergence of functions in $L_p$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Suppose we have a sequence of functions $f_n\ge 0$, $f_n\in L^p(\mu)$, $\int f_nd\mu=1$, and $f\ge 0$, $f\in L^p(\mu), \int fd\mu=1$, $0<p<1$  such that $$g_n:=\frac{f_n^p}{\int f_n^pd\mu}\to g:=\frac{f^p}{\int f^p d\mu}\text{ in } L^1(\mu)$$. Would this imply $$\int f_n^p d\mu\to \int f^p d\mu?$$
All I could show is that $\int f_n^p d\mu$ is bounded.

Suppose $M_n:=\int f_n^p d\mu\to \infty$. Then $$\mu(g_n>\epsilon^p)=\mu(f_n>\epsilon M_n^{1/p})\le \frac{1}{\epsilon M_n^{1/p}}\to 0$$ which says that $g_n\to 0$ in $[\mu]$-measure which is not possible.

I am wondering whether $\int f_n^p d\mu$ should, in fact, converge. Or, is there a counter-example to disprove this?

Comment: Write out the definition of convergence in $L^1$ norm. Does it help?

Comment: @abatkai: No. That doesn't seem to help.

Comment: what is $p$, $1<p<\infty$?

Comment: @Coiacy: $0<p<1$ as mentioned in the question.